# Created Java Spring Batch app to write to CSV file using FlatFileItemWriter, one field has commas in it and the file columns are messed up

Tags: java, spring-batch

I'm new to the spring batch and a Java novice. I am making an application that uses `JdbcCursorItemReader` to read data from a database and `FlatFileItemWriter` to write it to a CSV file. One of the columns has commas in it so the data is being separated at the wrong spot when it is written to the file. I've seen examples of how to fix this but none of them use `FlatFileItemWriter`. Is there an easy way to handle that without having to completely rewrite my entire code?

Example Code:

```
@Configuration
public class JobConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(step1())
                .build();
    }


    public Step step1() {
        log.info("Initializing Step1");
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<Invoice, Invoice>chunk(10)
                .reader(jdbcCursorItemReader1())
                .writer(flatFileItemWriter1())
                .build();
    }



    @StepScope
    @Bean
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<Invoice> jdbcCursorItemReader1(){
        log.info("Initializing Reader1");
        JdbcCursorItemReader<Invoice> jdbcCursorItemReader1 = new JdbcCursorItemReader<Invoice>();
        jdbcCursorItemReader1.setDataSource(dataSource);
        jdbcCursorItemReader1.setSql("select\n" +
                "SEGMENT1,\n" +
                "VENDOR_NAME,\n" +
                "INVOICE_NUM,\n" +
                "from Suppliers");
        jdbcCursorItemReader1.setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Invoice>(){
            {
                setMappedClass(Invoice.class);
            }
        });

            return jdbcCursorItemReader1;

    }

    @StepScope
    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemWriter<Invoice> flatFileItemWriter1() {
        log.info("Initializing Writer");
        FlatFileItemWriter<Invoice> flatFileItemWriter1 = new FlatFileItemWriter<Invoice>();


        flatFileItemWriter1.setResource(new FileSystemResource("random location/name.csv"));


        flatFileItemWriter1.setHeaderCallback(new FlatFileHeaderCallback() {
            @Override
            public void writeHeader(Writer writer) throws IOException {
                writer.write("Segment 1, Vendor Name, Invoice Num");
            }
        });
        flatFileItemWriter1.setLineAggregator(new DelimitedLineAggregator<Invoice>(){
            {

                setFieldExtractor(new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<Invoice>(){
                    {
                        setNames(new String[]{"segment1", "vendorName", "invoiceNum"});

                    }

                });
            }
        });
        return flatFileItemWriter1;
    }
```

Comment: @xerx593 yes sorry I was shortening the original code and accidentally left it in

Comment: the comma behind `"INVOICE_NUM"`(!?:)

Comment: You need a custom LineTokenizer or RowMapper that escapes commas in your actual data, see the duplicate question/answer thread.